# How to run setup in each pytest-xdist process

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, xdist, pytest-xdist

When my test runner starts, I want to set some stuff up (adjust sys.path, add some environment variables, start some global fixtures). What hook can I use to make these changes in each xdist process that is spawned?

I've tried overloading a couple of the normal pytest hooks, but they are run before the subprocesses are launched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest_xdist has additional hooks that can be used in the conftest.py ([list of hooks](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/blob/cd2696367873eb3440f221b5dcce3bea5db3939f/src/xdist/newhooks.py)). The relevant hook for this purpose is `pytest_configure_node(node)`, which is run after each new node is available and before it starts running tests.